# VS2008 - F5 or "Ctrl + F5" activates "Test"

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, project

In Visual Studio 2008, when i click on Debug > Start Without Debugging (or CTRL + F5) happens the same thing as if I clicked on Test > Run > Tests in Current Context / All Tests in Solution
After few attempts of fixing, now every time I run project I get this warning:

> "Executing the current test run will
>   produce a new test run result, which
>   will exceed the limit of 25 that is
>   currently specified. If you continue,
>   older test run results and their
>   associated deployments will be deleted
>   from the hard drive..."

Any ideas how to get things back to default state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you accidently set your test project as "startup project"?

If so: right click the project that you actually want to run, and pick "Set at startup project..." (or something along those lines). Next time you hit <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> this project will run.

Comment: is there some shortcut to change this cause i don't think i have accidently scrolled down, clicked on test projects and clicked on set as startup :)

Comment: Not one that I know of, but it is possible. Look through the menus in VS and see if the "Set as startup project..." option is available there as well. If it is, a keyboard shortcut might be mentioned here as well.

Answer (score 2):

This didn't answer it for me (it wasn't my start up project) but I found this other stack overflow post that did explain it:

[vs 2008 unit testing prompt meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917558/vs-2008-unit-testing-prompt-meaning)